# Parsing Quoted Strings and DateTime Offset - GROK and Logstash

Tags: docker, logstash-grok

With [Grok Debuger](https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/) I am trying to parse some custom data:

> 1 1 "Device 1" 1 "Input 1" 0 "On" "Off" "2020-01-01T00:00:00.1124303+00:00"

So far I have:

> %{INT:id} %{INT:device} %{QUOTEDSTRING:device_name} %{INT:input}
>   %{QUOTEDSTRING:input_name} %{INT:state} %{QUOTEDSTRING:on_phrase}
>   %{QUOTEDSTRING:off_phrase} \"%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:when}\"

However, I am getting things like double quotes around strings `%{QUOTEDSTRING)`, and two lots of hours and minutes with the time and date `%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:when}`

```
{
  "id": [
    [
      "1"
    ]
  ],
  "device": [
    [
      "1"
    ]
  ],
  "device_name": [
    [
      ""Device 1""
    ]
  ],
  "input": [
    [
      "1"
    ]
  ],
  "input_name": [
    [
      ""Input 1""
    ]
  ],
  "state": [
    [
      "0"
    ]
  ],
  "on_phrase": [
    [
      ""On""
    ]
  ],
  "off_phrase": [
    [
      ""Off""
    ]
  ],
  "when": [
    [
      "2020-01-01T00:00:00.1124303+00:00"
    ]
  ],
  "YEAR": [
    [
      "2020"
    ]
  ],
  "MONTHNUM": [
    [
      "01"
    ]
  ],
  "MONTHDAY": [
    [
      "01"
    ]
  ],
  "HOUR": [
    [
      "00",
      "00"
    ]
  ],
  "MINUTE": [
    [
      "00",
      "00"
    ]
  ],
  "SECOND": [
    [
      "00.1124303"
    ]
  ],
  "ISO8601_TIMEZONE": [
    [
      "+00:00"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Also, I am a little stuck when it comes to the `logstash.conf` as I am not sure what I would put as the `index` in the `output`.  The following code is from a previous example from github:

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
  }
}

filter {
  grok {
    match => { "message" => "%{IP:client} %{WORD:method} %{URIPATHPARAM:request} %{NUMBER:bytes} %{NUMBER:duration}" }
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "elasticsearch:9200"
    manage_template => false
    index => "sample-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
  }
}
```

I'm guessing mine would look something like this:

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
  }
}

filter {
  grok {
    match => { "message" => "%{INT:id} %{INT:device} %{QUOTEDSTRING:device_name} %{INT:input} %{QUOTEDSTRING:input_name} %{INT:state} %{QUOTEDSTRING:on_phrase} %{QUOTEDSTRING:off_phrase} \"%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:when}\"" }
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "elasticsearch:9200"
    manage_template => false
    index => "sample-%{????????}"
  }
}
```

Again I'm unclear as to what I am supposed to do with `"sample-%{????????}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In regard to the double-double-quotes: just use DATA instead of QUOTEDSTRING:

```
"%{DATA:device_name}"
```

Duplicated entries in the hours and minutes come from the timezone: first entry is the actual hour, the second one is the hour of the timezone. Same for the minutes.

To get rid of it you would need a custom pattern:

```
"(?<when>%{YEAR}-%{MONTHNUM}-%{MONTHDAY}[T ]%{HOUR}:?%{MINUTE}(?::?%{SECOND})?(?<ISO8601_TIMEZONE>Z|[+-](?:2[0123]|[01]?[0-9])(?::?(?:[0-5][0-9])))?)"
```

(if you are not interested in parsing the timestamp at all, just use DATA again).

So, your pattern might look like this:

```
%{INT:id} %{INT:device} "%{DATA:device_name}" %{INT:input} "%{DATA:input_name}" %{INT:state} "%{DATA:on_phrase}" "%{DATA:off_phrase}" "(?<when>%{YEAR}-%{MONTHNUM}-%{MONTHDAY}[T ]%{HOUR}:?%{MINUTE}(?::?%{SECOND})?(?<ISO8601_TIMEZONE>Z|[+-](?:2[0123]|[01]?[0-9])(?::?(?:[0-5][0-9])))?)"
```

Regarding index:

- you can omit it completely then the default one is used: `logstash-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}`
- you can use `sample-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}` if you want to have separate indexes for each day
- you can use `sample-` to have just one index
- you can use any other combination of the fields in your index pattern

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated!  One issue outside of this post was me naming the semantic`%{INT:input}` as it looks like its a reserved name and it was not showing in Kibana.  I named it to `%{INT:input_num}` and all is ok.  However, I'm getting a pop up notification saying `"cba24e50-4422-11ea-87a6-196047a921ba" is not a configured index pattern ID
Showing the default index pattern: "sample-*" (7ce7e210-442d-11ea-b280-431f48906f3f)` when I go to the Discovery tab.  Would you know what this means?

Comment: It's most likely some old non-existing index pattern cached somewhere in kibana. How are you accessing it? With a bookmark maybe? The index pattern may be present in the URL.

Comment: Ah okay, I've been using `docker-compose up` and `docker-compose down` then retyping `localhost:5601` in Firefox on a Mac.  You mean `sample-*` may be in the URL?

Comment: No, I meant that the old one 'cba24e50-4422-11ea-87a6-196047a921ba' is cached somewhere, in the browser maybe

Comment: Ah right, yeah that must be it, I wont worry then.  Thanks again for the answer, loads more questions about ELK, but for another day and time :-)  I'll mark your answer now.